# Resque caching active record call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, redis, resque

I have a simple resque job that accepts a model id, fetches it, and then calls a method on the fetched item.

```
class CupcakeWorker
  @queue = :cupcake_queue
  def self.perform(cupcake_id)
    @cupcake = Cupcake.find(cupcake_id)
    @cupcake.bake
  end
end
```

I queue it from a controller action using the 'enqueue' method

```
def bake
  Resque.enqueue(CupcakeWorker, params[:cupcake_id])
  render :json => 'Baking...'
end
```

The job queues and executes correctly.  However if I modify the record's data in the database and proceded to queue the job again the operation doesn't execute using the new values.

I can only get it to fetch the new values if I restart the resque worker process.  Is resque caching the object?  Is there a way to ensure it refetches from the database every time the worker is called?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little crude, but could work. You could call `reload` on the ActiveRecord model before doing any processing. This forces ActiveRecord to update the data.

The worker would then look like this:

```
class CupcakeWorker
  @queue = :cupcake_queue
  def self.perform(cupcake_id)
    @cupcake = Cupcake.find(cupcake_id).reload
    @cupcake.bake
  end
end
```

I'm afraid I don't know why Resque might be doing this, however. Try [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and see if you get better results.